# Наращение при указании на номер в цикле

Tags: наращение

Требуется при указании на номер в цикле ставить наращение?

Например: Я посмотрел инвенции. Предлагаю взять 11.

Comment: А Вы предпочитаете *смотреть* инвенции?

Comment: @grizzly Ну в смысле ноты, а не музыку.

Comment: Посмотреть — означает поиграть, ознакомиться с ней, почитать с листа.

Answer (score 1):

Если имеете в виду номер, будет уместен вариант «взять №11» (или «взять номер 11»); если речь об инвенции, то — «взять 11-ю».

Answer (score 1):

Наращение требуется, потому что без него смысл такой:
*Я посмотрел инвенции. Предлагаю взять 11 [штук].*